# Error in VSTS (Azure DevOps) - An operation is still in progress. Please wait and try again

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, git-checkout

I updated the Visual Studio 2017 to its latest version of 15.9.2 (as of 26/11/2018). After the update, it gives me an error, which says "***An operation is still in progress, Please wait and try again***" in the VSTS pane when I try to change the current branch to another branch.

I am sure that there is nothing running behind. Other than that, I have tried the same after a long time, still get the same error. Re-starting Visual Studio helps me to sort this out, but it is annoying to do it for each and every 'Push' I do.

Have anyone came across the same issue? Anyone having a solution or workaround, please?

[image]

[image]

Here, I was trying to switch from 'Sprint11-Kush' to 'Sprint11'.

Comment: This has been popping up for the past month and it's very annoying.  I keep having to open git bash to checkout the branch I want manually, which of course works without any issues.  You ever figure anything out?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did my own research to overcome this, but no luck as of yet.

Comment: Still occurs and I just upgraded VS2017 to the latest point release today, version 15.9.12.  Disappointing.  They seem to be pushing GIT hard yet it still doesn't work properly. :(

Answer (score 8):

Check that you are not executing your application, you cannot switch branches while running a solution in VS.
Stop your debug and switch branches

Answer (score 2):

Till visual studio extension is fixed execute below command to change branch

```
>git checkout <branch name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Great!  This can be considered as a workaround with no doubts :-)

Comment: tho you didn't answer ...why the issues was there in the first place